# Lost design view in windows forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a C# windows form project where on adding a custom control, I lost the design view (no error, just empty - works fine during runtime).

I added this custom NumericUpDown control:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29244/A-Derived-NumericUpDown-that-Provides-Handlers-for

And when I did that I got an error saying an EventHandlerService already exists so I fixed it by removing the bin and obj folders:
http://www.csharp411.com/ieventhandlerservice-already-exists-in-the-service-container/

Now, when I compile, I don't get an error and when I run, my form looks perfect but the Form.cs[Design] page is empty. It displays the standard empty page information that says "To add components to your class ..." When I check the .cspropj, everything looks ok:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
```

I changed the Form1.cs subtype from "Component" to "Form" but on recompiling that changes back to "Component".

Also, I can continue to add controls in the Form.Designer.cs page via code and the controls will show up during runtime but that's very challenging without the toolbox and the ability to drag-drop.

What other things can I try to get back the design view?

Comment: Does the designer work on a new form?

Comment: I am hoping you had a good commit in source control before you made the changes to roll back if you need to.  The other thing you can do is look to make sure that InitializeComponent is being called in the forms constructor.  Have you looked at the resx file for the form?  Does it still contain all the layout and controls?

Comment: When I delete/comment the custom control, then the form design reappears.

Comment: There is a standard InitializeComponent in the form.desginers.cs class which I used. I just looked at the resx file and comparing the resx with and without the custom controls looks the same (but w/o the custom controls the design shows up) so I'm guessing resx is not doing much here?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. The custom control was a separate class but I put it in the Form.cs class so the designer got confused. I just had to pull it out to its own separate class.